# Can I assign a value to a parent class attribute using super keyword from the child class in Java?

Tags: java, super

Newbie here trying to use the 'super' keyword in a setter method to assign a value to the parent class attribute 'price'. The parent class attribute is not getting updated outside the class where i called the setter though it appears to get updated within the class AND the "inherited?" version of price gets updated even though I did not use the 'this' keyword. What am I missing? Thanks.
`

```
package Practice.FruitConst;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
        Apple apple = new Apple();
    apple.setPrice(100.0);
       apple.pp();
        System.out.println("fruit " + fruit.price);

    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit{
    @Override
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        super.price = price;
    }

    public void pp(){
        System.out.println("apple " + this.price);

        System.out.println("fruit? " + super.price);
    }
}

class Fruit {

    String name;
    String color;
    double price;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + getClass().getSimpleName() +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

my output was:
apple 100.0
fruit? 100.0
fruit 0.0

i thought it should be:
apple 0.0
fruit? 100.0
fruit 100.0

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the scope of the `price` variable.  This is an instance variable which means that every instance of the type will have its own `price`.  It is defined on the `Fruit` class but it available to subclasses such as `Apple`.

You have created two *separate* object instances - one `Apple`, one `Fruit`.  They share no values between the two instances.  So, setting the price on one has no effect on the other.